# Create a command shell/menu in C

Tags: c, menu

As a Java programmer who wants to learn C, I try to create a command line based menu in C. The menu should read a line that is split by spaces that are divided into a matrix. Below are some Java code that does what I want: Can someone please help me to create a menu in C with this functionality?

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String [] command = line.split(" ");

            if(command[0].equals("c") && command[1] != null) {
                     ......
```

C:

```
char line[LINE_MAX];
    char *command;

    if(fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin) != NULL) {
        command = strtok(line," ");

        while(command != NULL) {
            printf("%s", command);
        }

    }
```

Comment: and here lies the reason people love languages like Java and C#... You get things like nice string tokenizers, and an actual string class. Doing this in C is ugly, but possible. What is the maximum number of items per line? Can you give some example inputs? This might help simplify the solution drastically

Comment: hehe :P Ye, but there must be a "easy" solution in C too.

Comment: The menu should accept a various number of items on line. help should be a input, new "message content that should consist of spaces, where the symbol " marks that spaces betweem " and " should not be split by the code "

Comment: @Fuzz Yeah C is sooo ugly. Instead of a method, you need to use a function. That's so nasty. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation of `fgets()` (for replacing `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`) and `strtok()` (for replacing `split()`).

**Edit**: here is my edit on your try:

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin) != NULL) {
    command = strtok(line, " ");

    if (command != NULL) {
        char *argument;

        printf("command = %s\n", command);
        while ((argument = strtok(NULL, " \n")) != NULL) {
            printf("\targument = %s\n", argument);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user Uhm, why don't you check the examples I linked to then?

Comment: I need some more help to get this to work the way I want: A sentence is divided up when the sentence contains a space. How can I put each divided word into an array commands[]: ex: hello my friend, commands[0] = hello, commands[1] = my, commands[2] = friend. Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: Just replace the printfs by something like `commands[i++] = argument`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

instead of `.split` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

instead of `.equals` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

instead of `.nextLine()` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/